# event post drag and drop not getting saved to database in fullcalender (angular)

Tags: angular, events, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I am using fullcalender(vs 4) in angular.On event receive I want to save data in database.What I observed is before rending of calendar services are getting injected successfully.but once rendering of calendar is completed then I am dragging and dropping events from external list.I am getting all information about event in "eventReceive(info)" but services are throwing error as it seems services are neither initialized nor injected.Any suggestion?.Is there any way to call external function within "event receive"Any help would be appreciated ?

Comment: @ADyson : do you have any idea on this?

Comment: I'm not an Angular expert at all, I only know about fullCalendar. But anyway no-one is going to have any chance of understanding the problem because you didn't provide any code or any error messages.

Comment: Actually after "eventReceive" I want to save the information in the database .for ex. I am trying to log the user                                                                       
             eventReceive: function(info) {
               console.log(this.dataShareService.getCurrentUser().userName);
           //saveMoves(info);        But it is not able to identify "datashareService" which is working fine in other code blocks.It seems once render is completed.there is no service available.So can I call any external method like "saveMoves(info)" to save the info.Your suggestion plz?

Comment: Please use the "edit" button (just under the blue "angular" tag) to add your code and other information to your question and then format it to be readable. Remember to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem. Please explain things like "not able to"...what **actually** happens in that case? e.g. do you get a console error, or similar? Please make it clear when you add the information. P.S. Like I said I don't know anything about Angular, and it sounds like an Angular-related issue. But perhaps someone else can.